# Displaying SubReport Data into a Microsoft Report Viewer Control with ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer, sql-server-express, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

I've got the main report displaying just fine. Can't get the subreport to display data. Parameters are setup and linked appropriately, but still nothing. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a bug I'm not aware of? Anyone else fighting with this? I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2008 on a SQL Express 2005 database.

Answer (score 0):

Have you handled the **SubreportProcessing** event?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf Me.SubreportProcessingEventHandler
End Sub

Public Sub SubreportProcessingEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
    'TODO
End Sub
```

Here's a link to the MSDN page on this: [click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.subreportprocessing.aspx)